# Derivative involving a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the first derivative of a SUM of all elements of an INVERSE of a square matrix (whose elements are functions of $z$) at $z=1$ knowing that all of the matrix' elements evaluate to $1$ at $z=1$.

This is needed in Statistics to find the expected number of trials to generate one of several preselected patterns (such as 3 consecutive sixes when rolling a die, etc.)

I believe the answer is: $-$ the reciprocal of the SUM of all elements of the inverse of the matrix of first derivatives (evaluated at $z=1$) but I don't know how to prove it (I have verified it up to 5 by 5 - quite difficult to go any higher).

P.S. What is the second derivative?

Comment: Your answer seems just to be a re-statement of the question, unless you're using some exotic definition of derivative.  If you're looking to verify that, then your question is probably more appropriate for [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com), although you will need to say some more about what you have tried—or at least, for example, what is your definition of the derivative.

Comment: Sorry. my stupid mistake: I was talking about the (elementwise) derivative of the corresponding INVERSE (now corrected)!

Comment: Singular matrices don't have inverses.

Comment: Singular matrices don't have inverses.  In particular, you can't sum the entries of the inverse of a singular matrix.

Comment: @LSpice: The way I understand the problem is that the function matrix is invertible in a punctured neighbourhood of $1$, so one has to compute the limes rather than directly evaluate at 1.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But the problem is that the limit (using L'Hospital) requires higher and higher derivatives (something like $2k$ for a $kxk$ problem, depending on how you go about it), which is not feasible beyond $k=5$, whereas Carlo's formula can be easily applied to $k$ in the hundreds or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first rephrase the question using formulas and then will provide a proof.

Start from the $n\times n$ matrix $A(z)$, such that $[A(1)]_{ij}=1$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots n\}$. The matrix $B(z)$ is the elementwise derivative, $B_{ij}=dA_{ij}/dz$.
Now the question which the OP asks is whether
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{i,j=1}^n [A^{-1}(z)]_{ij}=-\left(\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\sum_{i,j=1}^n[B^{-1}(z)]_{ij}\right)^{-1}\qquad\qquad(\ast)$$

For a proof I decompose $A=(z-1)B+v^\top v$, where $v=(1,1,1,\ldots 1)^\top$. I apply the [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity),
$$A^{-1}=[(z-1)B+v^\top v]^{-1}=(z-1)^{-1}B^{-1}\left[1-v^\top \bigl(z-1+vB^{-1}v^\top\bigr)^{-1}vB^{-1}\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow\sum_{i,j=1}^n [A^{-1}]_{ij}=vA^{-1}v^\top=\frac{vB^{-1}v^\top}{vB^{-1}v^\top+z-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{i,j=1}^n [A^{-1}]_{ij}=-\frac{1}{vB^{-1}v^\top}=-\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n[B^{-1}]_{ij}\right)^{-1},$$
which is the equation ($\ast$).

---

The OP also asks about second derivatives. Define $C_{ij}=d^2A_{ij}/dz^2$ and decompose $A=(z-1)B+\tfrac{1}{2}(z-1)^2C+v^\top v$. The Woodbury identity gives
$$vA^{-1}v^\top=\frac{vX^{-1}v^\top}{vX^{-1}v^\top+z-1},$$
$$X=B+\tfrac{1}{2}(z-1)C\Rightarrow X^{-1}=B^{-1}-\tfrac{1}{2}(z-1)B^{-1}C B^{-1}+{\cal O}(z-1)^2.$$
Thus we obtain the second derivative from
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n [A^{-1}]_{ij}=\frac{2-vB^{-1}C B^{-1}v^\top}{(vB^{-1}v^\top)^2}.$$

Comment: Not that there was ever any doubt, but your second-derivative formula verifies for up to 5 by 5 matrices (as far as one can get by brute force - after that, it would be algebraic nightmare. This is to emphasize the formula's importance: one cannot bypass it by taking a numerical limit for even relatively small matrices; this becomes an extremely ill-conditioned task).